# After selecting multiple rows from a table widget in PyQt, the cell widget(button) is shown in a wrong position

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to create a table widget with two buttons of each row and select some rows after inserting rows.

After selecting rows programmatically, I found the buttons in the table were moved to wrong positions. If I only selected a single row, everything was fine.

According to @eyllanesc suggestion, I tried to reproduce the issue, but it looks fine from the code below. My code was running on QGIS instead of the pure PyQt5, so I cannot really reproduce it.

I don't know why this issue happened and how to solve this.
Is there a way to reset the position of cell widget? Or can I manually set the position of a cell widget. If that's possible, maybe I can find a way to set it back. Thanks.

My code looks like:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 200)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        # add a button on the window
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setText("add rows")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 6, 1, 1)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Dialog)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(150)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(39)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(45)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(35)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(450,260)
        # set column count
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        # add two rows
        ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        for i in range(2):
            # button 1 of column1
            pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ui.tableWidget)
            pushButton1.setText('a' + str(i))
            ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, 0, pushButton1)

            # button 2 of column2
            pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ui.tableWidget)
            pushButton2.setText('b' + str(i))
            ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, 1, pushButton2)

            # an item of column3
            qItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i))
            ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 2, qItem)
            qItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 7)


        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", ""))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def addRows(self):
        # change to mutiple selection mode
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        
        # insert three new rows and select them
        for i in range(3):
            row = self.insertRow()
            # select the row
            self.tableWidget.selectRow(row)
        
        # change select mode back
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
    
    def insertRow(self):
         # insert a row to the table
        rowCount = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowCount)
        
        # row to insert 
        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1

        # button 1 of column1
        pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tableWidget)
        pushButton1.setText('a' + str(row))
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, pushButton1)

        # button 2 of column2
        pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tableWidget)
        pushButton2.setText('b' + str(row))
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 1, pushButton2)

        # an item of column3
        qItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, qItem)
        qItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
    
        return row


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(ui.addRows)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The screenshots of the table are:

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to reproduce the issue outside QGIS. But after playing around with it, I found a solution to my problem.

So after inserting some records, I call sortItems() to the table on the button column, then all buttons will display in the right position. Don't know why, but it works for me.

```
tableWidget.sortItems(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add buttons and connect your code. You need to enable sorting. I am also not sure why are you using extended selection. I hope code below resolves your issue.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1020, 950)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 581, 211))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()

        item = QtWidgets.QPushButton("its a button")
        
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 2, item)
        
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 2, item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1020, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Row5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Col3"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(3, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(4, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, @Elan, but I don't think the issue is related to sorting. I set setSortingEnabled() in my original codes.